# Changing ip by console, and update route table (on virtualbox)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iptables, ifconfig

Cheking routes before changes

```
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

Let's go to change the ip

```
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ sudo ifconfig enp0s3 192.168.0.30 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

The routables now is empty

```
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

Now, I was trying to add the rules...

```
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 enp0s3
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$

user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

**How, I must to add the before rules?**

```
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ netstat | grep enp0s3
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ 

user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ nmcli con
NAME       UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
Profile 1  64280569-78e6-496d-acc8-69215fd4c57e  ethernet  enp0s3 
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ 

user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ sudo dhclient
cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.xkMIfDSrZx which is empty
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ 

user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

another

```
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ resolvectl status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
  Current DNS Server: 190.157.8.100       
         DNS Servers: 190.157.8.100       
                      190.157.8.46        
                      100.70.133.50       
                      100.70.133.51       
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (enp0s3)
      Current Scopes: DNS          
DefaultRoute setting: yes          
       LLMNR setting: yes          
MulticastDNS setting: no           
  DNSOverTLS setting: no           
      DNSSEC setting: no           
    DNSSEC supported: no           
  Current DNS Server: 190.157.8.100
         DNS Servers: 190.157.8.100
                      190.157.8.46 
                      100.70.133.50
                      100.70.133.51
          DNS Domain: ~.           
lines 6-53/53 (END)
```

systemctl

```
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ systemctl | grep dhcp
user@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

*How check if dhcp is running? and more important how to stop it?*

Answer (score 0):

Anita, looks like the interface is configured to use DHCP and this service is interfering with your manual commands, your commands look correct. The output of your `netstat` command is probably mixing results of your manual commands and the DHCP service. The ip `169.254.0.0` in the output of `netstat` indicates that the network interface is being handled by a DHCP service, you have to stop it to configure the interface manually. You will probably need to disable other services such as network manager. You can also use the `ip route add` and `ip addr add` commands as alternative to `route` and `netstat`

Comment: Hi, but I'm can't to stop it.

Comment: Try with `sudo service network-manager stop`